# gnuplot graph with time fmt not working

Tags: linux, bash, gnuplot

I have created a script that logs various system resources, and will graph all data points into gnuplot with a nice smooth line. I am running into issues with gnuplot using my time format and plotting the data correctly. A sample of my data file is below

My time format = %H%M%S

"etc. etc." = hundreds of additional recorded times.

```
170554 3.0%
170556 2.7%
170558 2.6%
etc.
etc.
010218 2.1%
010218 2.3%
```

If the time of all data plots does not go over the 000000 mark, gnuplot graphs everything correctly. Once my data plots go over that 000000 boundary, gnuplot counts backwards in my time format, so it tries to plot everything that has not been recorded from 170554 - 010218 (numbers not recorded). 
Example. 170552 160424 150720 120818.

My gnuplot command I am using is below.

```
gnuplot -persist -e "set title 'Resource Monitor'; set timefmt '%H%M%S'; set xdata time; set xlabel 'TIME'; set ylabel 'PERCENT'; set yrange [0:101]' set xrange ['170554':'010218']" -e "plot 'log_file' using 1:2 title 'CPU' smooth Bezier"
```

So my question is...
Why is gnuplot not plotting my graph correctly (the way I want it to via time) and how can I fix this issue? Thank you.

Comment: You are missing a `set xdata time`.

Comment: I updated my gnuplot command, which helped with how I am visually displaying the TIME portion, but it is still trying to plot from the first time entry, backwards to the last time entry (missing all my data points).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation

> If `<ub>` is lower than `<lb>` the constraints will be turned off and full
>   autoscaling will happen.

To fix it, you will need to supplement your time data with additional "day" information, or find some other way to ensure that later times are never "lower than" earlier times.

Comment: I have changed my time formats to %d%H%M%S for all files/gnuplot. I will give this another try overnight and see what the results are. As it is the weekend (almost), if this works I will "Accept your answer" on Monday or Tuesday morning. Thank you!

Comment: Very good. Just be aware that you will then run into a similar problem over month boundaries. And if you supplement with month data, you'll still run into it over year boundaries (2016 coming up), etc. Design/operate accordingly...

Comment: Thank you very much. I plan to incorporate a complete modification to my time format throughout my entire script to accommodate these changes.